# Convert all the polygons of a FeatureCollection to editable polygons in GEE

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I need to convert all the polygons of a `FeatureCollection` in editable polygons (like the polygons you can draw with the drawing tools) so I can modify each of their shape if needed. The polygons represent burned areas during 1 year of a fire season.

```js
var table = ee.FeatureCollection("users/cecilianaval/Poligonos_SC_BAMS_2018");
print(table);

//Center and display the table, zoom = 8
Map.centerObject(table, 8)
Map.addLayer(table, {}, 'BAMS_2018');
```

[Code Editor script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/1124355a9e4947937258d8f6dce9edf8)

Comment: Your script imports a personal asset but it is not shared publicly. In the future, please [share the imported asset](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/asset_manager#sharing-assets) or mock up an example that reproduces the issue - thanks!.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `ui.Map.DrawingTools` module to do this.

1. Convert the `ee.FeatureCollection` to an `ee.Geometry`.
2. Transfer the resulting geometry to the client using `evaluate()`.
3. Add client-side geometry as a new layer of the drawing tools.

*Note: when you convert the feature collection to a geometry, all properties of the features are lost, which limits the utility of this operation.*

```js
// Here is my feature collection.
var fc = ee.FeatureCollection([
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(-122.0888, 37.2145)),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(-121.8087, 37.013)),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point(-122.0613, 37.0306))
]);

// Convert the feature collection to a geometry object.
var fcGeom = fc.geometry();

// Get the drawing tools.
var drawingTools = Map.drawingTools();

// Transfer the feature collection geometry to the client.
fcGeom.evaluate(function(geomList) {
  // Add the geometry as a layer of the drawing tools.
  drawingTools.addLayer([geomList], 'myGeometry', 'red');
});

// Center the map on the feature collection.
Map.centerObject(fc, 9);
```

[Code Editor script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/87ef1bfeaea5e452a1a210091123d8f3?as_external&noload=true)

For further reference on the `ui.Map.DrawingTools` module, please see this [guide](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/ui_widgets#ui.map.drawingtools) and [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorials/community/drawing-tools).